# Always getting null value in User Details from Azure AD after authentication .NET Core (3.0) Web API

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi

I am working in .NET Core 3.0 Web API and using Azure AD authentication.
So I'm trying to get User Name and Email of the active logged-in User from the Claims object.

Here is what I have tried

```
        var cu = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User;

        string username = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name);
```

When executing the username is null. This is the same when we change ClaimTypes.Email.

How can I get those details.

But I can see the value when debugging inside **User.Identity.Claims**. But I can't extract from there.

Answer (score 0):

[ClaimTypes.Name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimtypes.name?view=netcore-3.1) value follows the old SAML compatible format `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name` while JWT tokens uses  shorter versions like `name`.

Add the following line to your `ConfigureServices` method to build the claims collection using the JWT token claim names.

```cs
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = false;
```